# Get selected text including HTML tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the selected text with the HTML Tags. For example say a div tag is selected:

```
<div>hello There</div>
```

`window.getSelection()` will only give me `"hello There"` but i want `<div>hello There</div>`.

Comment: You are looking for [outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) property

Comment: Text selection is tricky to do cross browser (read: a nightmare). I would strongly suggest you use the excellent [Rangy library](https://github.com/timdown/rangy) to take care of it all for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery you could try the :contains selector (https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/):

```
$( ":contains('"+window.getSelection()+"')" )
```